# The SharePoint server was moved to a different location. ( Error from SharePoint site: HttpStatusCode Found The request failed with the error message

Tags: forms-authentication

> The SharePoint server was moved to a different location. ( Error from SharePoint site: HttpStatusCode Found The request failed with the error message

I am getting following error in "Crawl Log - URL".

It's FBA also NTLM is configured. Please check the following screenshot.

[image: NTLM with Custom LoginPage.aspx]

Please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: No one faced this issue?

Comment: I have a similar problem in SharePoint 2016...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The custom login page location:  ~/_layouts/15/ourcompany/login.aspx didn't work.  Removing the "~/" and making it _layouts/15... worked.  Strange!

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work for me. I removed the tilde and slash and SP duplicated the layouts path in the url: _layouts/15/CustomLogin/_layouts/15/CustomLogin/login.aspx